# explication of the function scipy.ndimage.convolve1d

Tags: python, arrays, math, scipy, convolution

when I have two array x1, x2 and I write this code :

```
n=len(x1)
p=len(x2)
S=convolve1d(x1,x2,mode=‘constant’)
```

mathematically
S is equal to what using x1,x2,n,p ?

and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read about [convolution](https://Have%20you%20read%20about%20convolution?%20It%27s%20rather%20complex%20thing..)? Formula is in `Discrete convolution` part.
It's rather complex thing...

In layman's term it might be considered as moving weighted average when one array (weights) slides along another.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer . I know about convolution and the meaning and the formula of it but mode='constant' what change in the normal convolution. That's new result of this convolution. And thank you again.

Comment: Here `(,mode=‘constant’, cval=0 by default)`  input is extended by zero values, so [1,2,3] becomes  [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0] before calculation

Comment: wow , so if I have x1=[a0,b0,c0] and x2=[a1,ab1] so s= x1[i]*x2[n-i] with i in ]-oo,+oo[ and x1 will be equal to  [......0,0,0,a0,b0,c0,0,0,.......]

Comment: Virtually - yes. Zero-extended array might be used for calculated (I don't know how it is really implemented), but x1 remains the same [a0,b0,c0]

Comment: If some answer is helpful, you can [accept it with green mark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)